# How the get the start time of the current browser session programatically using window or chrome api?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window, browser-extension

I'm developing the browser extension, and inside the background script, I would like to get the time when the current browsing session started. Is there a way how to get the timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

In the context of the background.js, you can use Performance API and try to call:

> newDate(performance.timeOrigin)

which will get the start time of the current browsing session